# Remember Compiler Warning Filters in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

In Visual Studio 2015 (possibly earlier as well) you can filter out Warnings and Errors of specific files, which comes in handy if you have a lot of foreign code in your project that fills your Warning overview with junk at the risk that you overlook your own Warnings.

When I restart Visual Studio, these filters are removed.
Is there a way to remember them?

**Edit:** Added a screenshot for clarity:

[image: Error List Filter]

Comment: Hmm, surely you are talking about the debugger notifications.  The ones you can temporarily suppress by right-clicking the Output window.  Permanently disable the ones you don't like with Tools > Options > Debugging > Output window.

Comment: @HansPassant I added a screenshot to clear up what I meant. I don't want to suppress certain types of warnings but all warnings for a set of files.